# Как выделить больше памяти под число ассемблер?

Tags: ассемблер

Как видно на фото, числа до от -128 до 127 записываются в нормальном ввиде, а числам больше или меньше - не хватает места, на сколько я понимаю. Как сделать так, чтобы оно записывалось в нормально виде? Т.е. чтобы 130 записывалось как 130 в память, а не как -127.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `db` - байт. Вероятно, нужен `dw` - слово, два байта.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас проверю

Answer (score 1):

На данные числа у вас и хватает памяти и записываются они тоже правильно, просто вы выбрали неверное отображение. Вместо `Float` нужно выставить `UInt` и будет вам счастье.

---

`db` - выделяет один байт, то есть диапазон его значений либо **0..255**, либо **-128..127** *(в зависимости от типа **unsigned(беззнаковое)** или **signed(знаковое)**)*.

Чтобы лучше понять как это работает почитайте про [дополнительный код](https://microkontroller.ru/programmirovanie-mikrokontrollerov-avr/pryamoy-obratnyiy-dopolnitelnyiy-kod-dvoichnogo-chisla/).

---

Вообще, `Float` обычно занимает 4 байта и является типом представления чисел с плавающей точкой.

Видимо на размерности ниже своей отображается как `signed int`.